# How other buttons disabled when pressed the button?

Tags: cordova

I creat a phoneGap app for android. I have a few buttons which have onclicklistener. If I press one, I can press others or I can click them same time(and they work). I do not want it. Everytime when I press one of them others should work after it finish not in same time.

Comment: how can you click it all @ sametime?

Comment: this buttons have animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple: on button click, disable all buttons till operation finished and then enable them again

```
$(":button").prop('disabled', true);
```

This code should disable all buttons (`<input type="button"...>`) To enable it back, change prop value, to `false`